# Circle around a point in the chart

Tags: excel, geometry

I have a (x,y) coordinate which will be plotted in a scatter plot. I need a circle of radius R to be drawn around the point plotted.

Thanks and Regards,
Prabhu.C

Comment: give more info about your data and chart and post what you have tried so far including code vba if any.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My work is about collection different points (x,y) as coordinates. Please just consider any coordinates of a point. for eg i have a point (652792, 7911523) and r value is 450m. now with tha above point is ploted in xy scatterpolt. I need circle around the point with 450 radius.

Answer (score 1):

A 'bare bones' example which may get you started.  You will need to play with scaling, units and positioning etc. to suit your context.

This will draw a circle with no fill and a red circumference, with a commented-out line to give it a solid fill (change .Visible to msoTrue).

[image]

```
Sub drawCircle()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cLeft As Long, cTop As Long
Dim cX As Long, cY As Long, cDia As Long
Dim c1 As Shape

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
cX = Range("A2")
cY = Range("B2")
cDia = Range("C2").Value * 2

cLeft = cX - (cDia / 2)
cTop = cY - (cDia / 2)

    With ws
        Set c1 = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, cLeft, cTop, cDia, cDia)
            With c1
                .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
                .Line.Weight = 2
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                '.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'eg Red fill
            End With
    End With

End Sub
```